# React Link sending to appended address rather than replacing current

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am looking to create a link from a 'ViewItemDetails' page to a 'EditItem' page, but when I copy a link I used previously, I am getting directed to the following link: `http://localhost:3000/ViewItemDetails/1/EditItem/1`, and I am trying to get the `/EditItem/1` to replace the `/ViewItemDetails/1` but it seems to be appending it to  the end of the url (`http://localhost:3000/EditItem/1`). since I am trying to use the location twice is it carrying over from the previous link? If so is there another way to write this link where it goes off of the base url '/' rather than the current url?

Previous link (Leads to `http://localhost:3000/ViewItemDetails/1`):

Router:

```js
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route index element={<App />} />
                    <Route path="/Wishlists" element={<ItemContainer />} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/ViewItemDetails/:id"
                        element={<ViewItemDetails />}
                    />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
```

Item.jsx component:

```js
<Link
    to={`/ViewItemDetails/${props.id}`}
    state={{ item: props }}
    className="fill-parent">
</Link>
```

New Link (Added to ViewItemDetails component):

```js
    <Link
        to={`EditItem/${item.id}`}
        state={{ itemId: item.id }}>
        <button>Edit Item</button>
    </Link>
```

index.js router:

```js
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route index element={<App />} />
                    <Route path="/Wishlists" element={<ItemContainer />} />
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/ViewItemDetails/:id"
                        element={<ViewItemDetails />}
                    />
                    <Route exact path="/EditItem/:id" element={<EditItem />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
```